# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Face Detection

Tags: javascript, rotation, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use face detect service.

I have seen that face detect works only if image is rotated in the right direction.

BUT, if I have an image rotated, how can I automatically rotate it?
Actually I have a form where there is A canvas with the image to rotate, and another one where there is the image rotated, like in the picture below:

[image]

My goal should be to send the image to Microsoft API rotated correctly (the second one canvas), and receive the ID of the face detected.
How could I do that?
Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance for answers

Answer (score 0):

If the image contains rotation information in exif, the Face API will rotate the images automatically. But if the information is lost, AFAIK, there is no way to determine the rotation status.